# Why is this CRON task not running a Python Program Raspberry Pi

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi

I have a CRON task scheduled as followed:

```
30 18 * * 1-5 python python /home/pi/myscript.py
```

Why is it not executing?

Comment: Cron writes logfiles. Anyhow, this is less of a programming question and more of a "how to use cron", so it's more suitable to superuser.com

Comment: Redirect the output to a file and see?

Comment: `python python myscript.py`?

Answer (score 0):

it may be a permission issue, try running this in the console

`chmod -R 777 /home/pi/myscript.py`

Comment: Surely this should be a comment?

Answer (score 0):

The format of writing cron job is incorrect.
Correct entry for this is as following:

```
30 18 * * 1-5 "python /home/pi/myscript.py"
```

If you are using Python 3.x then change accordingly i.e.:

```
30 18 * * 1-5 "python3 /home/pi/myscript.py"
```